# trying to print the list the variable name of the list

Tags: r

So my list format is

```
$department_name

[1] "CS" "SYS" "BIOL" "CHEM" "MATH" "STAT" 

$class_time

[1] 8:00 9:30 10:00 11:00 12:00 12:15
```

I tried to type my code as

```
mylist <- list(department_name, class_time)
```

to print out the exact same output, but it instead shows

```
[[1]]

[1] "CS" "SYS" "BIOL" "CHEM" "MATH" "STAT" 

[[2]]

[1] 8:00 8:00 9:30 10:00 11:00 12:00 12:15 12:15
```

Can you please help me if there is any way that I can print out my output with the variable names not [[1]] or [[2]]?

Also, what function do i use to figure out the what time the most popular class time is.
I know the answer should be 8:00 and 12:15, but don't know how to approach to define they are the most popular class time.
Can you guys tell me how i take the initial step?

Comment: Not clear if the list you showed at the beginning is an input or your desired output. You also are asking multiple questions. See the `?names` function to set names to objects.

Comment: that's my desired output like i said "want to print out the exact same output". I didn't know asking multiple question was not allowed. Sorry about that!

Comment: As Nicola has mentioned see ?`names`. Some of the examples with lists can be found here . http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1365/lists/5383/introduction-to-lists#t=20170215090126757459

Answer (score 0):

You have just to name the elements of your list. Here is a reproducible example:

```
test <- list(
  a = c("a", "b", "a"),
  b = c(1,2,3))
```

It will return your desired output:

```
list(A = test$a, B = test$b)
```

But not this one:

```
list(test$a, test$b)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in my case because it can't be as a data frame bc i don't have the same amount of rows and columns. Also, list(A = test$a, ...) doesn't work either.

Comment: It does not need to be a data frame. I have edited my answer according to this =) You can also specify the names of the elements of your list with: `names(mylist)` please refer to the other comments (@theArun)